# chef edit an existing config via a wrapper cookbook

Tags: apache, chef-infra, cookbook

I have two wrapper cookbooks and a community cookbook `apache2`. The 1st wrapper cookbook is our `core_dispatcher` wrapper that uses `apache2` widely used for all clients. The 2nd wrapper is for a particular client `client_dispatcher` cookbook. I want to make a change to only one client so I am using the 2nd `client_dispatcher` wrapper that wraps the `core_dispatcher` wrapper.

This is the line I want to add to `client_dispatcher` wrapper

```
ErrorDocument 404 /content/en/error/404.html
```

I created a new template `anon_errordoc.erb` in my `client_dispatcher` and just hard code it `ErrorDocument 404 /content/en/error/404.html` in the erb file. I want this to be added to my existing vhost `anoncom.conf` that already exist on my server.

in my client_wrapper recipe I have the following:

```
include_recipe 'core_dispatcher::default'

edit_resource(:template, '/etc/httpd/sites-available/anoncom.conf') do
  source 'anon-errordoc.erb'
  cookbook 'client_dispatcher'
end
```

Error after running chef-client

```
Recipe: <Dynamically Defined Resource>
* template[/etc/httpd/sites-available/anoncom.conf] action create

================================================================================
Error executing action `create` on resource 'template[/etc/httpd/sites-available/anoncom.conf]'
================================================================================

Chef::Exceptions::FileNotFound
------------------------------
Cookbook 'client_dispatcher' (0.1.13) does not contain a file at any of these locations:
  templates/amazon-2017.09/dispatcher-vhost.conf.erb
  templates/amazon/dispatcher-vhost.conf.erb
  templates/default/dispatcher-vhost.conf.erb
  templates/dispatcher-vhost.conf.erb

This cookbook _does_ contain: ['/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/client_dispatcher/templates/default/filters-anon.conf.erb','/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/client_dispatcher/templates/default/anoncom-errordoc.erb']

Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/apache2/definitions/web_app.rb

 28:   template "#{node['apache']['dir']}/sites-available/#{application_name}.conf" do
 29:     source params[:template]
 30:     local params[:local]
 31:     owner 'root'
 32:     group node['apache']['root_group']
 33:     mode '0644'
 34:     cookbook params[:cookbook] if params[:cookbook]
 35:     variables(
 36:       :application_name => application_name,
 37:       :params           => params
 38:     )
 39:     if ::File.exist?("#{node['apache']['dir']}/sites-enabled/#{application_name}.conf")
 40:       notifies :reload, 'service[apache2]', :delayed
 41:     end
 42:   end

Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/apache2/definitions/web_app.rb:28:in `block in from_file'

  template("/etc/httpd/sites-available/anoncom.conf") do
  params {:template=>"dispatcher-vhost.conf.erb", :local=>false, :enable=>true, :server_port=>"80", :server_name=>"dev-anoncom.ctmsp.com", :server_aliases=>["dev-anoncom.ctmsp.com"], :docroot=>"/var/www/cache/publish/anoncom", :name=>"anoncom"}
  action [:create]
  retries 0
  retry_delay 2
  default_guard_interpreter :default
  source "dispatcher-vhost.conf.erb"
  cookbook "client_dispatcher"
  variables {:application_name=>"anoncom", :params=>{:template=>"dispatcher-vhost.conf.erb", :local=>false, :enable=>true, :server_port=>"80", :server_name=>"dev-anoncom.ctmsp.com", :server_aliases=>["dev-anoncom.ctmsp.com"], :docroot=>"/var/www/cache/publish/anoncom", :name=>"anoncom"}}
  declared_type :template
  cookbook_name "core_dispatcher"
  mode "0644"
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  path "/etc/httpd/sites-available/anoncom.conf"
  verifications []
end

Platform:
---------
x86_64-linux


Running handlers:
Running handlers complete
```

Comment: What version of Chef is this? Given the output, I'm guessing something pretty old?

Comment: I am running chef version 12.19.36